# Bash: How to calculate?

Tags: linux, bash, math

I need to do some basic math `(720/304) * 360`

but bash acts very strange:

```
echo "720/304 * 360" | bc
720

echo "(720/304) * 360" | bc
720

echo $(((720/304) * 360))
720
```

Comment: bash can only do integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `bc -l` to get non-integer results of each operation.

```
echo "720/304 * 360" | bc -l
```

or, shorter in bash:

```
bc -l <<< '720/304*360'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reverse the / and * if you can work with an integer result:

```
echo $((720*360/304))
852
```

Then it does not need temporary non-integer results (which were in your order `int(720/304) = 2, 2 * 360 = 720`)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this :

```
 echo 'scale=2; 720/304 * 360' | bc
```

the `scale` is needed here, like I does. And better use *single quotes* to avoid possibly *shell expansion*.

With [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you can do this too (*here-string*):

```
bc <<< 'scale=2; 720/304 * 360'
```

Or using *here-document* :

```
bc<<'EOF'
scale=2; 720/304 * 360
EOF
```

Comment: Why bc does't round the number? `echo 'scale=2; 720/304 * 360' | bc >
849.60`

Answer (score 1):

you should do math calc with either awk or bc, if you want to have certain precision. but one should be careful to use rounding with `bc`. since some operation would give "unexpected" result: for example:

```
kent$  echo 'scale=2; 720/304 * 360' |bc 
849.60
kent$  echo 'scale=3; 720/304 * 360' |bc         
852.480
kent$  echo 'scale=4; 720/304 * 360' |bc 
852.6240
```

so I recommend `awk`:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.2f\n", 720/304*360}'
852.63
```